# Passing value from form to service and then using that value to fetch data to another component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently passing a value from form to a service. Then I'm fetching data from server based on that value and I would like to send that data to another component which is not related to the form component.

```
Form -> Service -> Server

Server-> Service -> Component
```

**Service**

```
      _currentMovie: Observable<IMovie>; // This is where the fetched data gets saved

      getSingleMovieById(movieId: number){
        let urlWithId: string = this._singleMovieUrl.concat(movieId.toString());
        this._currentMovie = this._http.get<IMovie>(urlWithId);

  }
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this._movieService._currentMovie.subscribe((value)=> console.log(value));
}
```

I get the correct data from server to the service, but can't use it in the component. This gives an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

Error Log:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at MovieService.getSingleMovieById2 (movie.service.ts:80)
    at MovieDetailsComponent.getCurrentMovie2 (movie-details.component.ts:81)
    at MovieDetailsComponent.ngOnInit (movie-details.component.ts:63)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12411)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13935)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14712)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MovieDetailsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
```

**Form Component HTML**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/details']" href="/details" (click)="setCurrentMovie2(movie)">Details</a>
```

**Form component Typescript**

```
  setCurrentMovie2(movie: IMovie){
    this._movieService.setCurrentMovie2(movie.MovieID);
  }
```

**Service**

```
  setCurrentMovie2(Id: number){
    this.movieID = Id;
    console.log("movieid", this.movieID);
  }
  getSingleMovieById2(): Observable<IMovie>{
    let urlWithId: string = this._singleMovieUrl.concat(this.movieID.toString()); // This is where error happens
    return this._http.get<IMovie>(urlWithId); 
  }
```

**Details Component**

```
  getCurrentMovie2(){
    this._movieService.getSingleMovieById2().subscribe((value)=>console.log(value));
  }
```

Comment: I think _currentMovie is not initialized when you call ngOnInit() because getSingleMovieById is not yet called, therefor the undefined. You can use a Subject<IMovie> in your Service, initialize it in the constructor. Subscribe to this subject in your component. And then, trigger the subject.next() with the result of getSingleMovieById() which was called by your Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Service**

```
public id: number;

 public getSingleMovieById(): Observable<IMovie> {
  const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${this.id}`;
  return this.http.get<IMovie>(url);
}

// call this method from the first component which you have a form in it.
public setId(id: number): void {
   this.id = id;
}
```

**Component**

```
public ngOnInit(): void{
  this.movieService.getSingleMovieById().subscribe((value)=> console.log(value));
}
```

And if you have provided your service in the component level. Please remove that and provide it in a only module.

Comment: I can't call the .getSingleMovieById(id) method from the second component, because the id comes from the component which has form.

Comment: I tried this but then I get an error saying ERROR
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: from where are you getting the error.. provide the error log

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: Its better if you can provide full code of those two components and the service. May be a code snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171533/discussion-between-sander-and-anuradha-gunasekara).

Comment: The problem was because the service was provided in the component level, I removed the service from FormComponent and DetailComponent and put it in App Module Array.